# How to write an R for loop which uses key-value pairing?

Tags: r, for-loop, key-value

I have the following function that I want to run as a for loop in R:

```
<Term>_summer_UP <- as.data.frame(allGO["<GO.ID>"])

write.table(<Term>_summer_UP,"<Term>_summer_UP.csv",sep=",",quote=FALSE,row.names=FALSE)

rm(<Term>_summer_UP)
```

I want to use a dataframe as input for the 'term' and 'GO.ID' variables :

[image]

How do I write a for loop that will write the data collected from allGO["<GO.ID>"] to the relevant Term (key-value pairing)? Also, how do I get my for-loop to iterate through csv file name? ("**Term**_summer_UP.csv")

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to use a `For` loop - this looks like a good time to use the `mapply()` function.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a lookup data frame named `GO_ID_lookup` - please check the column names for your `allGO` table, as colons are typically coerced to `.` unless you use `check.names = FALSE`.

```
GO_ID_lookup <- data.frame(
  GO.ID = c("GO:0006869",
            "GO:0042157",
            "GO:0010030"),
  Term = c("lipid_transport",
           "lipoprotein_metabolic_process",
           "positive_regulation_of_seed_germination")
)

# without an provided dataset I created this for a toy example
allGO <- data.frame(
  `GO:0006869` = 1:10,
  `GO:0042157` = 21:30,
  `GO:0010030` = 31:40,
  check.names = FALSE
)

mapply(FUN = function(id,term) {
  write.table(
    x = allGO[id],
    file = paste0(term,"_summer_UP.csv"),
    sep = ",",
    quote = FALSE,
    row.names = FALSE)},
  id = GO_ID_lookup$GO.ID,
  term = GO_ID_lookup$Term)
```